# sign soap envelope with smart card

Tags: .net, wcf, security, smartcard, sign

I try to sign soap envelope with smart card.

I recently tried, signing body outside and inject it to soap envelope, but it didn't give me the right result.

I also tried to sign it with setting client certificate, which I took from local certificate store, but as there was no private key on it, it didn't neighter give me the result.

For one week, i've been trying. Please help.

Sorry for my awful english by the way.

Comment: What kind of smartcard are you using? Is it accessible via CSP?

Comment: Yes, i can access it via CSP. I can also sign something with csp and verify it. But i dont know how can I sign an envelope..

Comment: am i the only one in the world ? :(